# Regex to match numbers between dates

Tags: php, regex

I need some help to match some numbers that are between two dates, like this:
26/03/2021**3539-4 / 107512-8**26/03/2021R$

I tried (a lot), and in regexr.com my pattern works, but doesnt work when I try in PHP preg_match

My code:

```
$str = '26/03/20213539-4 / 107512-826/03/2021';
preg_match('/(?<=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})([^]*)(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})/', $str, $match);
echo $match;
```

Can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a quote of `^` in your POSIX character group. In your pattern, replace `[^]` with `[\^]`. Then it'll match.

Because you see, just `[^]` is not a valid group (it's not group with one character `"^"`). No, instead in your case: `[^]*)(?=[0-9]` it's na **inverted** group with `]*)(?=[0-9` characters (because syntax `[^ ]` inverts the group). So you must fix that somehow. Either by quoting `\^`, or introducing some other form of matching any character.

Did you want to match any character including newline? Because if that's the case then simply use `.` and add flag `s` (lowercase) - dot match all.

And instead of using `preg_match()`, you should use [pattern($p)->test($string)](https://t-regx.com/).